# How to get jira project issues total count faster using jira-python?

Tags: python, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, python-jira

The following code returning all jira's and taking more time. i want to get the total jira count faster, without jira details

```
jira.search_issues('project=PROJ and assignee != currentUser()')
```

From the following link we can get total count using JQL, How to do the same using jira-python. 
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-29903

Tried following code by adding maxResults=0, but it is returning empty list instead of total jira count.

```
jira.search_issues('project=PROJ and assignee != currentUser()', 
                   startAt = 0, 
                   maxResults = 0)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the argument `json_result=True`

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('https://jira.atlassian.com')
jira.search_issues('project=CLOUD and assignee != currentUser()', 
                   startAt=0, 
                   maxResults=0, 
                   json_result=True)
```

Output:

```
{'issues': [], 'maxResults': 0, 'startAt': 0, 'total': 2704}
```

You can see additional options with Python's built-in **help**:

```
help(jira.search_issues)
```